# Excel - If a word is present turn a number to 0?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a simple sheet that adds totals. I need to be able to put the word LD in a cell and have all numbers in that column be read as zero, otherwise they are added as normal.

Example:

`B6:B22`, `C6:C22` have the numbers 10 in them. The totals are added row wise, so the totals for each are 20.
If I put "LD" in `B23`, I need another formula to read 10 instead of 20.

I was trying to use an IF formula but cannot seem to get anything working.

I apologize if this is unclear, I will do my best to clarify if I need to.

Thank you!

Comment: @Tribic: Yes. That helps immensely. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you get the totals (20) in `D6:D22`.
So try this formula in `D6` and copy it down to `D22`

```
=IF(B$23="LD";10;SUM(B6:C6))
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the sum of the actual values in the cells, try this (put it in `E6` and copy down to `E22`).

```
=SUM(IF(EXACT($B$23,"LD"),0,B6),C6)
```